# How do I create lists in Python while using object oriented programming?

Tags: python, oop, list

I'm trying to create an initial attribute that also creates a list.

```
class Player(object):
    """A virtual player"""

    def __init__(self, name, items, max_items = 5):
        # still need to create item list
        self._items = []
        self.name = name
        self.max_items = max_items
        print "\nA new player named",self.name,"has been created.\n"

    def inventory(self):
        if len(self.items) > 1:
            print "\nThe inventory is:"
            print self.items
        else:
            print "Your inventory is empty"

    def take(self, new_item):
        if self.items <= self.max_items:
            self.items.append(new_item)
        else:
            print "\nSorry, your inventory is completely full."

    def drop(self, drop_item):
        if drop_item not in self.items:
            print "That item does not exist in your inventory."
        else:
            self.items.remove(drop_item)



def main():
    player_name = raw_input("What name do you want to give the player?: ")
    player = Player(player_name)

    choice = None
    while choice != 0:
        print \
        """
        Player Menu

        0 - Quit
        1 - Print inventory
        2 - Add an item
        3 - Drop an item
        """
        try:
            choice = int(raw_input("Choice: "))
        except (ValueError):
            print "Invalid number."

        if choice == 0:
            print "\nGoodbye\n"
        elif choice == 1:
            player.inventory()
        elif choice == 2:
            new_item = raw_input("What item do you wish to add to your inventory?: ")
            new_item = new_item.lower()
            player.take(new_item)
        elif choice == 3:
            drop_item = raw_input("What item do you want to drop?: ")
            drop_item = drop_item.lower()
            player.drop(drop_item)


# main
main()
raw_input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please provide a minimal source code example, and describe the expected behavior.

Comment: You need to put in more effort than just pasting a page of code.

Comment: `self.items` or `self._items`? What is the name of your property?

Answer (score 2):

`self._items = []` is absolutely correct.

But you have some logical errors in your code:

`if len(self.items) > 1:` should be `if len(self.items) > 0:` or even better `if self.items:` - you want to check if theres 1+ in the item, not if there's more than one item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    inp = raw_input  # Python 2.x
except NameError:
    inp = input      # Python 3.x

def describe(lst):
    if not lst:
        return "nothing"
    elif len(lst)==1:
        return "a {0}".format(lst[0])
    else:
        return 'a {0}, and a {1}'.format(', a '.join(lst[:-1]), lst[-1])

class Player(object):
    """A virtual player"""

    def __init__(self, name, items=None, max_items=5):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.max_items = max_items
        self.items = list(items)[:max_items] if items else []
        print("A new player named {0} has been created.".format(self.name))

    def inventory(self):
        if self.items:
            print("Your pockets contain: {0}.".format(describe(self.items)))
        else:
            print("Your pockets are empty.")

    def take(self, new_item):
        if len(self.items) < self.max_items:
            self.items.append(new_item)
            print("You take the {0}.".format(new_item))
            return True
        else:
            print("Your pockets are too full.")
            return False

    def drop(self, drop_item):
        try:
            self.items.remove(drop_item)
            print("You drop the {0}.".format(drop_item))
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print("You have no {0}!".format(drop_item))
            return False

def main():
    print("Welcome, adventurer! What is your name?")
    char = Player(inp(), ['string', 'blue key', 'pocketknife'])

    commands = ['go', 'take', 'drop', 'inv', 'help', 'quit']
    roomItems = ['ball', 'apple', 'dragon']
    while True:
        print("You are in the Baron's antechamber. You see {0}.".format(describe(roomItems)))

        cmd = [i.lower() for i in inp('> ').strip().split()]
        verb = cmd[0]
        if verb in commands:
            if verb=='go':
                dir = ' '.join(cmd[1:])
                print('You try to go {0}, but a giant kangaroo kicks you back into the antechamber.'.format(dir))
            elif verb=='take':
                item = ' '.join(cmd[1:])
                if item in roomItems and char.take(item):
                    roomItems.remove(item)
            elif verb=='drop':
                item = ' '.join(cmd[1:])
                if char.drop(item):
                    roomItems.append(item)
            elif verb=='inv':
                char.inventory()
            elif verb=='help':
                print("I know the words {0}.".format(', '.join(commands)))
            elif verb=='quit':
                break
        else:
            print("I don't know how to '{0}'.".format(verb))

    print('The Baron has decided! There is a grating noise - the floor drops away like a trapdoor, and {0} plummets into darkness. THE END!'.format(char.name))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
    inp("Press enter to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the attibute `self._items` in the constructor but `self.items` else-where.

Maybe that is your problem, otherwise you need to explain what your problem is more clearly.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the list issue. On an unrelated note, I'm getting an error saying the init attribute is only being passed 2 arguments. The self argument is a give, the name seems solid, the items is too, and the max_items is set to a default. I can't figure out with the third argument is supposed to be.

Comment: `player = Player(player_name)` only has self + one argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first attempt at OOP. How can I alter it so that it takes another argument?

Comment: @Paul R: To answer your question: `player = Player(player_name, another_arg)`.